# Why this validator return None while Django's return useful message?

Tags: python, django

Below is the code for the Validator, Why `None None` is print? This same code is in [django 1.6](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/core/validators.py).

```
In [1]: %paste
class SVNPathValidator(object):
    message = 'Enter a valid value.'
    code = 'invalid'

    def __init__(self, verify_existed=True, message=None, code=None, path_type=0, rev=None):
        '''
            file_type:
                0 file
                1 dir
        '''
        if message is None:
            self.message = message
        if code is None:
            self.code = code
        print self.message, self.code
        self.path_type = path_type  
        self.rev = rev 

    def __call__(self, value):
        print self.message, self.code
## -- End pasted text --

In [2]: validator=SVNPathValidator()
None None

In [3]: validator('svn://10.10.10.10/repo')
None None
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think it would do anything else. You don't pass either the message or the code when you instantiate the object, and you don't set them in the `__call__` method.

The code is *not* the same as the Django code you link to. On the contrary, all the Django versions have the opposite of your code: `if self.message is not None` etc.

Comment: It's all my fault. I got it right using `if self.message is not None`, but when Class variable message and code are used?

Answer (score 0):

The function of you code is to set those two variables to None -- though I assume it wasn't meant to be.

```
def __init__(self, verify_existed=True, message=None, code=None, path_type=0, rev=None):
    if message is None:
        self.message = message
    if code is None:
        self.code = code
```

First it checks whether the arguments are `None` and if they are, it assigns them as instance variables. Nowhere does `self.message` or `self.code` get assigned to anything else.